# random string spinner issue

Tags: php, string

i want to make a spin function to spin a string but i fased problem for doing it. I allready know how to sping
words in string like changing {hi|hello} but what i want is different it is ranom spin in a string

```
$spin_words=array('Word1','Word2','Word3');
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
```

so i want to add the words in random like

> Lorem Ipsum is simply **[Word1]** dummy text of the printing and
>   typesetting industry.

or

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing **[Word2]** and
>   typesetting industry.

or

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
>   typesetting industry **[Word3]**.

so any help guys

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$words = array('Word1','Word2','Word3');
$text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
echo wordInString($text,$words);
echo wordInString($text,$words);
```

Output Example

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy Word1 text of the printing and typesetting industry.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing Word2 and typesetting industry.
```

Function Used

```
function wordInString($text,array $words) {
    $textNew = array();
    $p = mt_rand(0, substr_count($text, " "));
    $tok = strtok($text, " \n\t");
    $x = 1;
    while ( $tok !== false ) {
        $textNew[] = $tok and $x == $p and $textNew[] = $words[array_rand($words, 1)];
        $tok = strtok(" ");
        $x ++;
    }
    return implode(" ", $textNew);
}
```